# Java Swing: How to make JLists resize properly when GridBagLayout column is set to grow, ignoring the JList's item widths?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I got the following GridBagLayout:
[image]

The first and the last column with the JLists are set to `grow: 1`. I wan't these JLists to always have the same width, no matter how wide the contained items are. How can I achieve this?

I already tried it with `list.setFixedCellWidth(100)`, but then the surrounding JScrollPane does not work anymore.

Comment: Um, `GridBagLayout` and `GridBagConstraints` don't have a `grow` property...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I bet he is using WindowBuilder. In its Column/Row properties dialog you can set grow property with a spinner. It then sets the columns/row Weights array accordingly.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can also reproduce your issue and provide a solution for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set prototype cell value on the JLists

```
jList.setPrototypeCellValue("asdf");
```

Set the same text on both JLists. JList will then "pretend" that all the items are as wide as provided text. This width will be used to determine if scrollbars are needed so you should find the longest item you are adding to the JList and set the prototype as that.

Setting fixed cell width with `setFixedCellWidth(int)` will work too, but you will have to calculate the width of the widest text yourself.

Comment: Just understand that this will effect the width of ALL the cells, regardless of their needs, so if a cell overflows the horizontal size of the prototype cell, it won't show the horizontal scroll bars - yes, I spent a lot of time debugging it

Comment: To address MadProgrammers comment. If you are adding items dynamically and the new item is wider than the current prototype it will be cut off (because JList will ignore its width). To work around it you could loop through all the items allready in the lists and compare if the new item is wider than those. Then you can set the cell width / prototype cell value again and revalidate, repaint the panel.

Comment: Thank you for that simple solution, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

So, you problem is multi-leveled.  The problem is, the `JList` provides two values which are used to make determinations about the layout of the `JList`

The first is `getPreferredSize`.  This will be used by the `JScrollPane` to make determinations about when it needs to show it's scrollbars.

The second is `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize`.  This provides a hint to the `JScrollPane`, which will affect it's `preferredSize`, which provides a hint to the layout manager about how it would like to be laid out.

One possible solution would be to provide more information about the `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize` so that both `JList`s generated the same value.  Then, with some clever layout constraints, you could keep both lists at the same size.

So, we start by extending from `JList` and providing a means to see the `preferredScrollableViewportSize` to it.

```
public class FixedSizeList<E> extends JList<E> {
    
    private Dimension preferredScrollableViewportSize;

    public FixedSizeList(ListModel<E> dataModel, Dimension preferredScrollableViewportSize) {
        super(dataModel);
        this.preferredScrollableViewportSize = preferredScrollableViewportSize;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        if (preferredScrollableViewportSize != null) {
            return preferredScrollableViewportSize;
        }
        return super.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize();
    }
    
}
```

Now, personally, I'd probably be tempt to use the `FontMetrics` and the `JList`s `Font` to make determinations about how best these values should be used, so you could provide a `column` and `row` value (or use the `visibleRowCount` property).  This then means that the values are "characters" rather then pixels, but that's just me.

Next, we need to constraint the layout so that both lists will won't to occupy 50% of the available space.

```
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.weightx = 0.5;
gbc.weighty = 1.0;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

JList shortList = new FixedSizeList(new ShortModel(), new Dimension(150, 300));
JList longList = new FixedSizeList(new LongModel(), new Dimension(150, 300));

add(new JScrollPane(shortList), gbc);
gbc.gridx += 2;
add(new JScrollPane(longList), gbc);

gbc.weightx = 0;
gbc.gridx = 1;

JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
    buttons.add(new JButton(Integer.toString(index)), gbc);
}
gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 1;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.weighty = 1.0;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
add(buttons, gbc);
```

That's a fun way of saying "both lists will fill the remaining available space". Since we've additional constrained the `scrollableViewportSize`, this will provide equal spacing for both lists

[image: Equal column widths]

This is some what "heavy" handed (IMHO), but it beats looping through all the elements of both models every time you add a new element to the this

## Runnable example...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListModel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1.0;
            gbc.weighty = 1.0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

            JList shortList = new FixedSizeList(new ShortModel(), new Dimension(150, 300));
            JList longList = new FixedSizeList(new LongModel(), new Dimension(150, 300));

            add(new JScrollPane(shortList), gbc);
            gbc.gridx += 2;
            add(new JScrollPane(longList), gbc);

            gbc.weightx = 0;
            gbc.gridx = 1;

            JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
                buttons.add(new JButton(Integer.toString(index)), gbc);
            }
            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weighty = 1.0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            add(buttons, gbc);
        }

    }

    public class FixedSizeList<E> extends JList<E> {

        private Dimension preferredScrollableViewportSize;

        public FixedSizeList(ListModel<E> dataModel, Dimension preferredScrollableViewportSize) {
            super(dataModel);
            this.preferredScrollableViewportSize = preferredScrollableViewportSize;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
            if (preferredScrollableViewportSize != null) {
                return preferredScrollableViewportSize;
            }
            return super.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize();
        }

    }

    public class SizableModel extends DefaultListModel<String> {

        public String makeText(int length) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
            for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
                String text = Integer.toString(index);
                sb.append(text.substring(text.length() - 1));
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

    }

    public class ShortModel extends SizableModel {

        public ShortModel() {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
                addElement(makeText(Math.max(1, rnd.nextInt(5))));
            }
        }

    }

    public class LongModel extends SizableModel {

        public LongModel() {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
                addElement(makeText(Math.max(5, rnd.nextInt(15))));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GridBagLayout is not capable of doing that.  However, [SpringLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/SpringLayout.html) is.

SpringLayout is cumbersome to use, so it’s not usually a good choice, but there are some things it can do that other layouts can’t.  In this case, its ability to make one component’s size constraints depend on another component’s size constraints is applicable:

```
JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 6, 6));
buttonsPanel.add(new JButton("\u2190"));
buttonsPanel.add(new JButton("\u21c7"));
buttonsPanel.add(new JButton("\u21c9"));
buttonsPanel.add(new JButton("\u2192"));

JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
centerPanel.add(buttonsPanel, new GridBagConstraints());
centerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 12, 0, 12));

centerPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(
    centerPanel.getPreferredSize().width,
    centerPanel.getMaximumSize().height));

JList<String> leftList = new JList<>(new String[] {
    "Erwartete Gäste pro Segmentcode",
    "Restaurant Auslastungsvorschau",
    "Restaurant Tagesauslastung",
});

JList<String> rightList = new JList<>(new String[] {
    "Info",
    "Ressourcenauslastung",
    "Provisionsanzeige",
    "Umsatzstatistik",
    "Top Anzahl/Umsatz",
    "Mitgliedsübersicht",
    "Gastherkunft",
    "Capture rate",
});

JScrollPane leftPane = new JScrollPane(leftList);
JScrollPane rightPane = new JScrollPane(rightList);

SpringLayout.Constraints leftConstraints =
    new SpringLayout.Constraints(leftPane);

SpringLayout.Constraints rightConstraints =
    new SpringLayout.Constraints(rightPane);

SpringLayout.Constraints centerConstraints =
    new SpringLayout.Constraints(centerPanel);

Spring width = Spring.max(
    leftConstraints.getWidth(),
    rightConstraints.getWidth());

Spring height = Spring.max(
    leftConstraints.getHeight(),
    rightConstraints.getHeight());

leftConstraints.setWidth(width);
leftConstraints.setHeight(height);
rightConstraints.setWidth(width);
rightConstraints.setHeight(height);
centerConstraints.setHeight(height);

centerConstraints.setConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,
    leftConstraints.getConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST));

rightConstraints.setConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,
    centerConstraints.getConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST));

SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
JPanel listsPanel = new JPanel(layout);

listsPanel.add(leftPane, leftConstraints);
listsPanel.add(centerPanel, centerConstraints);
listsPanel.add(rightPane, rightConstraints);

// Set width of container
layout.putConstraint(
    SpringLayout.EAST, listsPanel, 0,
    SpringLayout.EAST, rightPane);

// Set height of container
layout.putConstraint(
    SpringLayout.SOUTH, listsPanel, 0,
    SpringLayout.SOUTH, rightPane);
```